# Cross platform Google Sheets API implementation in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: google-api, xamarin.forms, google-sheets-api

I am creating an app in a **Xamarin.Forms** PCL project that uses the Google API to push some data to a spreadsheet. However, when I install the Google.Apis.Sheets.v4 nuget package, I cannot access the GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker from the PCL. When I used an interface and implemented in the Android app, it throws an unsupported exception when it attempts to open the web browser.

It says something like

> "Failed to open browser with URI 'blah blah blah'.

I tried just catching that exception and using Device.OpenURI to open it, but it does not return to the app after the user signs in. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I'm having the exact same problem right now. I was able to work around pulling data down by using their rest api instead of the service in their nuget package, but I can only get read access that way. I can't update rows. Always get a 401 on POST's.

Comment: Sadly, no. Google and .Net don't exactly get along as a rule, so they don't exactly make it easy. I ended up just doing something else.